# On WP Multi sites how many sites...!

Tags: multisite, shared-hosting

He I'm Hieu, I work as IT Engineer in An Thanh company Vietnam.

We have 5 hosts (Shared host: Godaddy) with more that 60 sites each.

On the moment all of this main sites (5) go down regularly with 500 errors.

All on different times and duration and go from some minutes 5, 15 and more to some hours.

We haven't found the problem yet and because we don't have much experience with WP and, specifically, Multisite, we need to ask some questions.

1. What is the maximum number of sites for a WP Multisite?  What are the limits on the database?
2. This interruption that we have I'm sure that is happening before with some with your other customers can you help me to know what the reason is...!

I hope you can help me on the right way

Tran Trung Hieu
IT AN THANH
Vietnam

Comment: The is no limit for WordPress Multi Site. The same software is used by WordPress.com and they have millions of blogs hosted on their servers. Here you can find an answer from Andrea_r (WordPress multisite question-answerer) about this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/multisite-table-limit-and-file-system-limits

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you're using GoDaddy shared hosting to host 60-site multi-site systems and still expecting it to work.

GoDaddy shared hosting is not appropriate for this kind of setup. Once you get past the 5-6 sites range, you need a dedicated server for them.

Get a better hosting account. Pay for it.

Answer (score 1):

Wp multi site has no limit or just depends on your server being that you are on a shared server it would be a lot less.  As for the errors you are better of asking your host.

Answer (score 1):

WP Multisite has no limit, but it is important that you [devide the database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2825/wordpress-sharding-which-multi-db-plugin-to-use) for many sites. I have an install with curretn 9999 sites and 1024 databases, but is hard to work on this with an tool how phpMyAdmin, but possible.